# how to get default google map marker to represent user's current location

Tags: android, google-maps

i am using a mapview in my android application and to represent user's current location i have used a custom image. But now i want to replace that custom image by google default map marker(for eg. a blue pulsing dot or blue arrowhead/beackon).

cam somebody please help me....!!

Comment: MyLocationOverlay class didn't help me.......i need to set the default map marker in such a way that it looks like it is blinking and there is a circle around it.....please help me to sort out my problem

Answer (score 1):

use enableMyLocation() in MyLocationOverlay class:

```
MyLocationOverlay mMyLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapView); 
mMyLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation(); 
mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download these Icons using the static url's.

- Here is one source: [Google Earth Icons list](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/geicons.htm)
- Here is another : [Google Maps Icons](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-icons/)

You can use these code bases as examples.

- [IncidentMap](https://github.com/ushahidi/Ushahidi_Android/blob/40652a2af85b08aea2ce33c8337168b84344dfb2/src/org/addhen/ushahidi/IncidentMap.java)
- [MapView Baloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/blob/715d6252ce67382e43e86dfdf656e5cbdbd04165/android-mapviewballoons-example/src/mapviewballoons/example/MyMap.java)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) class.

```
mMyLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapView); 
mMyLocationOverlay.enableCompass(); 
mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);
```

Comment: MyLocationOverlay class didn't help me.......i need to set the default map marker in such a way that it looks like it is blinking and there is a circle around it.....please help me to sort out my problem

Comment: The blinking blue? With a larger blue highlight depending on the accuracy? That is MyLocationOverlay.

Comment: MyLocationOverlay class is really not helping me...if i am replacing my existing code with MyLocationOverlay class then i am getting a null pointer exception..

Comment: That is another problem probably due to you not implementing it correctly.

Comment: use enableMyLocation() in MyLocationOverlay class